# How do I write a csv to a specific sharepoint folder?

Tags: python, pandas, sharepoint

I am trying to write to my company's sharepoint. However, I am having problems doing this. I have tried to use sharepoints capabilities of linking my computer to the sharepoint, and then accessing it using the path provided. Howeverthis method does not work since the script it can only update if my computer is on. I am able to get the website address to the sharepoint's specific folder path I need. However I don't know how to write to it using a website address.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas 
from datetime import date 
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

east_time = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
date_time_east = datetime.now(east_time)
date_time_east = date_time_east.strftime("%H")
update_time = "11"

if date_time_east == update_time:
    today = date.today()   
    data = pandas.DataFrame(dataset) 
    path = "sharepoint path"
    date = today.strftime("%m.%d.%y")
    csv = ".csv"
    final_path = path + date + csv
    data.to_csv(final_path)
```

Comment: are you getting any sort of errors or is the file just not being saved in the right place? if the later can you see where the file is saved

Comment: How does your path (anonymised) look like? Is it a local path? If it is an URL, there is a solution to upload CSV files with Python here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67604748/42659